# Header "List of Tables" in the following page

Tags: table-of-contents, bibtex, header-footer, fancyhdr, dvipdf

I have written my thesis using `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside, openany]{ThesisStyle}`, where `ThesisStyle` is a custom documentclass.

After compiling, the header of List of Tables appears in the Abstract. How can i change my preamble, so that "List of Tables" appears on the following page?

---

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside, openany]{ThesisStyle}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}                       % Sets fancy header and footer
\fancyfoot{}                            % Delete current footer settings
\fancyhead{}    %by smita

\fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries\thepage} %%%%by smita:
% pages and right on odd pages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}      % Chapter in the right on even pages
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\rightmark}}     % Section in the left on odd pages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
%\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup
\newpage

%\thispagestyle{plain}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\linespread{1.25}
%\newpage
\begin{center}
%%\noindent\rule[2pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
{\LARGE\textbf{Abstract}}

\end{center}
Some text .....some text...some text
\end{document}
%\noindent\rule[2pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
```

Comment: Hello @ssinghal and welcome to the forum! Can you expand your code-example to be compilable?

Comment: Can you put a minimal working example? And try to put `\newpage` between `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, maybe it works.

Comment: Hello,I have updated the post with compilable code.

Comment: \markboth{}{} when starting the abstract.

Comment: @Johannes : Thanks a lot !! Now thesis seems fine. Thanks everybody for the prompt reply.